# Can two identical strings be two separate instances in C#?

Tags: c#, string

In C#, strings are interned. That is, if I create the string `foobar` and use it a second time, C# will only have one instance of the string in memory and although I will have two references, they both will be pointing to the very same string instance. This is one reason why strings are and have to be immutable in C#.

Now, my question is, whether it is possible to somehow create two identical strings so that they are not being interned, but that we end up with two different string instances in memory, with two different addresses, that contain the very same text?

If so, how?

And, is this something than can happen accidentally, or do you need to construct a scenario explicitly for this case?

And, finally: Supposed there are two separate string instances in memory with the same value, are they equal (in terms of `==`)? If so, how does `==` work? First compare by reference, then by value, or…?

Comment: "In C#, strings are interned." No, they are not. String *constants* are interned. String instances are interned only if you call `String.Intern`. Interning every intermediate string would be very wasteful.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that. What does that mean for two string instances that have the same value? Do they refer to the same "object"?

Comment: @GoloRoden `==` on strings does a string comparison (letter-by-letter, if it were) in C#. It doesn't matter if they are interned or not, and it doesn't matter which memory they refer to.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I don't thing so, `string s1 = "Int32";
string s2 = typeof(int).Name;
Console.WriteLine(object.Equals(s1, s2));` Is this interning?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: try `Object.ReferenceEquals()`. `Object.Equals()` does what you expect -- it tells you the strings have the same contents.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, You say: `String instances are interned only if you call String.Intern`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Yes, and? Your code is not a counterexample. `"Int32"` and `typeof(int).Name` are not the same string. (If you want to get precise, it's string *literals* that are interned -- it doesn't matter if the literal is assigned to a constant or a variable.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert `String constants are interned.` and `it's string literals that are interned`  are different things.

Comment: By the way, this [Understanding C#: String.Intern makes strings interesting](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/08/understanding-c-stringintern-m.html) is quite good.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: fortunate that I only posted a comment and not an answer, then.

Comment: Another point about the == operator: The equality operators for C# strings are overloaded to give them value type semantics.  It is this overloading that makes a == comparison compare the text of a string and not that the references are equal.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> In C#, strings are interned.

No. In C# strings **are permitted to be [interned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern)**.  That is a very different statement.

> That is, if I create the string foobar and use it a second time, C# will only have one instance of the string in memory and although I will have two references, they both will be pointing to the very same string instance

No. Again, in C# the runtime is *permitted* to decide that one "foobar" is the same as another and intern them, but it is not *required* to do so.

Of course, if you copy a reference then the reference is copied. But if you create a second string that looks the same as an earlier string, there is no requirement that it be interned.

In practice, strings are interned when they are literals:

```
string x = "foobar";
string y = "foobar";
// x is reference equal to y
```

or when they could be computed to be identical by the compiler:

```
string x = "foobar";
string y = "foo" + "bar";
// x is reference equal to y
```

Or when you explicitly tell the runtime that you want to intern a particular string.  Otherwise strings are not typically interned:

```
string x = "foobar";
string y = "f" + x.Substring(1); 
// x and y are not reference equal
```

Comment: In addition, I want to mention, that the interning is work only within the boundary of assembly. Mentor can correct me if I wrong.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Good point. Typically string literals are interned automatically when they occur twice in the same assembly, but not necessarily when two literals occur in two different assemblies. Again the runtime could choose to do so, but in practice I do not believe it does.

Answer (score 13):

Only string literals are interned. Run-time interning is expensive, so dynamically created strings are not interned (unless you intern them explicitly by calling `String.Intern`).

The following strings all are different instances (you can check it using `object.ReferenceEquals()`):

```
string str1 = "foo";
string str2 = "FOO".ToLower();
string str3 = new StringBuilder().Append("f").Append("oo").ToString();
```

The `==` operator is overloaded for `string` to compare them by value, not by reference

```
public static bool operator == (String a, String b) 
{
   return String.Equals(a, b);
}
```

When using the `==` operator, you have to remember that operators are not polymorphic. So if the compile-time type of both operands is `string`, the `string` overload will be used. If at least one of them is `object`, the reference comparison will be performed

```
string str1 = "foo";
string str2 = "FOO".ToLower();
object str3 = str2;
bool valueComparison = str1 == str2;     // true - the same value
bool referenceComparison = str1 == str3; // false - different instances
```

Comment: `str3` isn't a string unless you add `.ToString()` to the chain. Also, you may wish to add a demonstration of `Object.ReferenceEquals()` to show they're truly different objects.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very simple test proving that 2 equivalent strings don't always point to the same object reference:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str1 = "foo";
    string str2 = "f";
    str2 += "oo";
    Console.WriteLine(str1 == str2); // prints true (value equality check)
    Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(str1, str2)); // prints false (reference equality check)
}
```